# .NET: Windows Forms + Console / Prevent closing

Tags: .net, forms, console

I have a Windows Forms application which opens a console using AllocConsole. It works fine, but the problem is when I close the Console by clicking the "X"-Button, the entire application exits too, but I want that only the Console Window should close and the Application should continue as usual. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to programmatically hide the window that you've allocated - use FreeConsole.

The X button on the alloc'd console works like the X button on your WinForm - it will tickle the Form_Closing() event I guess.

You'd need some logic in that event handler to decide whether to actually close the form or not. One possibility:  grab the mouse position and see if it is within the bounding box for the Form.  If it is, then conclude that the Form's X was clicked, and close the app.  If the mouse is NOT within the form, then conclude that the console X was clicked, and call FreeConsole.

I haven't tried this.

Comment: Doesn't work. The Form_Closing event does not get triggered by the console window. I've tried the Application.ApplicationExit event too, but it's not possible to cancel that event.

Comment: What do you really want to do, anyway?  The console that can be opened this way is pretty rudimentary, I always thought it was mostly useful for diagnostics or debugging.  Is this really something you want to expose in your app's UI ?